# Docker MariaDB ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mariadb

I saw many questions on this topic but it doesn't work for me.
I got this error while connecting on the DB with user root.
Here is my mariadb configuration from docker:

```
docker run -d \ --name=mariadb \ -e PUID=1002 \ -e PGID=1002 \ -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ROOT_ACCESS_PASSWORD \ or -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e TZ=Europe/London \ -p 3306:3306 \ -v /media/RAID250/DockerConfigs/MariaDB:/config \ --restart unless-stopped \ lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb:latest
```

I tried to setup manually the password but still not working.
I tried to delete all files in this folder /media/RAID250/DockerConfigs/MariaDB to make a fresh install of mariadb... no effect.
I tried to stop the mariadb services but none cmd line works.
I also tried mariadb-secure-installation once I'm in the container after this cmd line: docker exec -it mariadb bash:

```
root@c7afe65d1643:/# mysql -u root -p Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've made yourself the victim of an *"insurmountable one-liner"* by running the command in a single long line.

Let's try and break your command down, line by line:

```
docker run -d \
 --name=mariadb \
 -e PUID=1002 \
 -e PGID=1002 \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ROOT_ACCESS_PASSWORD \
 or -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
 -e TZ=Europe/London \
 -p 3306:3306 \
 -v /media/RAID250/DockerConfigs/MariaDB:/config \
 --restart unless-stopped \
 lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb:latest
```

Now it's pretty easy to spot the error - you're defining the variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` two times - and in addition it's difficult to decipher what the sudden `or` (which is most likely an instruction comment) is doing to the command.

This shows why it's a good idea to create an easily manageable startup script for your containers. You could create the script `docker_mariadb.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -d \
  --name=mariadb \
  -e PUID=1002 \
  -e PGID=1002 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<the-one-and-only-true-password-here> \
  -e TZ=Europe/London \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -v /media/RAID250/DockerConfigs/MariaDB:/config \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb:latest
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ./docker_mariadb.sh
```

Now you can just run `./docker_mariadb.sh` to start the container, and you have documented your startup configuration for the container as well.